# R: How to write it in more efficient, more compact, way the code that repeats using the same kind of variables

Tags: string, r, for-loop, dataframe, performance

I have a `data.frame` `DAT` in which there 8 columns containing the strings in the following format (these are the multiple choice answers to eight questions of a quiz):

```
  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8
1 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
2 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
3 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
4 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
5 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
6 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
```

I would like to convert it to the following:

```
 q11 q12 q13 q21 q22 q23 q31 q32 q33 q41 q42 q43 q51 q52 q53 q61 q62 q63 q71 q72 q73 q81 q82 q83
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
6   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

So I write the following code:

```
NAMES.Q = paste(rep("Q",8), c(1:8), sep="") 
DAT[ which(DAT[NAMES.Q]=="NULL"),]<- NA # to set to NA skipped questions
NAMES.q  = paste(rep("q",8), c(1:8), sep="")
```

The following code is to convert the strings into `0` and `1` numeric values.

```
q1 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q1"]), strip.white = TRUE)
q2 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q2"]), strip.white = TRUE)
q3 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q3"]), strip.white = TRUE)
q4 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q4"]), strip.white = TRUE)
q5 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q5"]), strip.white = TRUE)
q6 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q6"]), strip.white = TRUE)
q7 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q7"]), strip.white = TRUE)
q8 <- read.csv(text = as.character(DAT[,"Q8"]), strip.white = TRUE)
names(q1) = paste("q1", 1:3, sep = "")
names(q2) = paste("q2", 1:3, sep = "")
names(q3) = paste("q3", 1:3, sep = "")
names(q4) = paste("q4", 1:3, sep = "")
names(q5) = paste("q5", 1:3, sep = "")
names(q6) = paste("q6", 1:3, sep = "")
names(q7) = paste("q7", 1:3, sep = "")
names(q8) = paste("q8", 1:3, sep = "")
q1[is.na(q1)] <- 0
q2[is.na(q2)] <- 0
q3[is.na(q3)] <- 0
q4[is.na(q4)] <- 0
q5[is.na(q5)] <- 0
q6[is.na(q6)] <- 0
q7[is.na(q7)] <- 0
q8[is.na(q8)] <- 0
qs<-cbind(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8)
```

The code works, but I find it very difficult to read and maintain.

Would you suggest a loop or another way of writing this information in my main `data.frame` (DAT) without creating a new `data.frame`?

Comment: Aren't you creating lots of new dataframes yourself in your approach? What do you mean with "without creating a new data.frame"?

Comment: @vaettchen
exactly, I am creating extra (unnecessary?) dataframes because I am not sure how I to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strsplit` instead of `read.csv`. Add some `lapply` loops and you are all set.

```
DF <- read.table(text="  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8
1 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
2 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
3 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
4 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
5 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
6 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,", header=TRUE)

DF2 <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(DF, function(x) {
  res <- strsplit(x, ",")
  res <- lapply(res, as.numeric)
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  res[is.na(res)] <- 0  
  res
  }))

#  Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q2.1 Q2.2 Q2.3 Q3.1 Q3.2 Q4.1 Q4.2 Q5.1 Q5.2 Q5.3 Q6.1 Q6.2 Q6.3 Q7.1 Q7.2 Q8.1 Q8.2
#1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
#2    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
#3    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
#4    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
#5    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
#6    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
```

Comment: I have followed your example and it worked exactly as you explained. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

First, read the data with `read.table`. The default field separator in `read.table` is ‘white space’, i.e. the separator *between* the concatenated "Q" columns.

Then you may use a function in package `splitstackshape`, `concat.split.multiple`, to split the concatenated columns. By not specifying `split.cols`, the columns that need to be split, *all* columns are split. The default separator character (`seps`) used in each column is `,`.The default shape (`direction`) of the resulting data frame is "wide". Thus, in this case you only need to supply the name of the data frame.

```
df <- read.table(text="  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8
1 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
2 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
3 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
4 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
5 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,
6 ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,, ,,1 ,,1 ,1, 1,,", header=TRUE)

library(splitstackshape)

# split columns
df2 <- concat.split.multiple(df)

# or explicitly writing out the arguments
df2 <- concat.split.multiple(data = df, split.cols = names(df), seps = ",")

# replace NA with 0
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
df2

#   Q1_1 Q1_2 Q1_3 Q2_1 Q2_2 Q2_3 Q3_1 Q3_2 Q3_3 Q4_1 Q4_2 Q4_3 Q5_1 Q5_2 Q5_3 Q6_1 Q6_2 Q6_3 Q7_1 Q7_2 Q7_3 Q8_1 Q8_2 Q8_3
# 1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
# 2    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
# 3    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
# 4    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
# 5    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
# 6    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
```

Comment: it is a great suggestion. I did not know about this `splitstackshape` package! It could be very useful in my case.  However, I tried to run it and I get the following error: 
`Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 15000`. I am not sure, but it might be the case, that my data is too long (17,000).

Comment: Hard to say what goes wrong. It worked nicely with the format of the example data you provided though...

Comment: I shortened the data, and it worked as a charm. Very elegant solution!

Comment: Great to hear! How large is your original data? It might be worth to ping the maintainer of the package and describe this potential 'issue'.

Comment: @inarts, I tried the function in my answer on a data frame consisting of 10000 replicates of your example data, i.e. 60000 rows. It worked fine. Perhaps you need to check your original data. Maybe there are some peculiarities that are not captured in the example data? Cheers!

Comment: It might be safer (or more transparent) to use something like `concat.split.multiple(df, names(df), ",")` but it's hard to say why this error came up without having a small sample to reproduce it....

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for your comment. I added a version with explicit arguments.